# Numpy find the first i for which np_array[i] > factor *np_array[i] / np_array[i-1]

Tags: python, numpy

For ordered np array (np_array),

I would like to find the first index for which :

```
np_array[i] >  factor *np_array[i] / np_array[i-1]
```

is there any numpy way of doing it?
(not a "for loop")

Comment: use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to vectorize this and get the first index

```
(np_array[1:] > np_array[1:] * factor / np_array[:-1]).argmax()
```